# Nativescript-Vue two columns per row

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

How can I view image two columns per row with nativescript-vue by using RadListView, as picture below:

[image]

Comment: Use [Grid item layout](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/ListView/item-layouts#radlistview-item-layouts) in RadListview and set the span count to 2.

Answer (score 2):

Like Monoj answered in the comment here a little example:

```
<RadListView ref="mylistView" 
    for="item in items"
    layout="grid" 
    gridSpanCount="2">
    <v-template>
        ...
    </v-template>
</RadListView>
```